# Unable to resolve symbols when importing my development haxelib

Tags: haxe

- In the haxelib project folder, I am running `haxelib dev cc_gfx .`.
- In the importing project folder, `haxe build.hxml`.

I get the error `src/shader/Shader.hx:3: characters 7-19 : Type not found : gfx.Vector2f`.

`build.hxml`:

```hxml
-cp src
-lib cc_gfx
-main shader.Shader
-lua out/main.lua
```

`haxelib.json`:

```json
{
  "name": "cc_gfx",
  "license": "MIT",
  "description": "Bindings to the gfx library for ComputerCraft.",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "classPath": "src",
  "releasenote": "Initial release.",
  "contributors": ["James King"]
}
```

`Shader.hx`:

```hx
package shader;

import gfx.Vector2f;

class Shader {
    static public function main() {
        var v = new Vector2f(1, 1);
    }
}
```

`Vector.hx`:

```hx
package gfx;

public class Vector2f {
    var x : Float;
    var y : Float;

    Vector2f(x : Float, y : Float) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually not related to the files being in a Haxelib.

> src/shader/Shader.hx:3: characters 8-20 : Type not found : gfx.Vector2f

`import gfx.Vector2f;` is trying to import a [module](https://haxe.org/manual/type-system-modules-and-paths.html) that doesn't exist, it's actually named `Vector` (since the file name is `Vector.hx`). The module name doesn't *have* to match the class name, but then the import needs to be adjusted to `import gfx.Vector;`. Or just change the file name to `Vector2f.hx`.

---

After that is fixed, the compiler will report two more errors, since the code in `Vector` has some syntax issues:

> src/gfx/Vector.hx:3: characters 1-7 : Unexpected public

Types in Haxe are `public` by default, so there's no `public` modifier allowed. After that:

> src/gfx/Vector.hx:6: characters 5-13 : Unexpected Vector2f

That's not how you declare a constructor in Haxe. `Vector2f(x:Float, y:Float)` should be replaced with `public function new(x:Float, y:Float)`.